# LWJGL Stencil shadow problem

Tags: lwjgl, shadows

I've a problem with shadow (Stencil).
So when i draw the shadow they looks good, but when the object to draw is underground his shadow is wrongly rendered.
My game is do with LWJGL/GL11.

Normal render:
[over http://web-survival-machines.crystal-serv.com/shadow%20problem%201.jpg](http://web-survival-machines.crystal-serv.com/shadow%20problem%201.jpg)
Bad renders:
[over http://web-survival-machines.crystal-serv.com/shadow%20problem%202.jpg](http://web-survival-machines.crystal-serv.com/shadow%20problem%202.jpg)
[over http://web-survival-machines.crystal-serv.com/shadow%20problem%203.jpg](http://web-survival-machines.crystal-serv.com/shadow%20problem%203.jpg)

the light is on the right of the scene.

code used to render:

```
public void render(){
    TimeLogic.updateMSTimer(); TimeLogic.updateDelta();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, BufferUtils.arrayToBufferFloat(lightPos));


    //-----

    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, ~0);
    glStencilOp (GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
    drawScene();
    /*do->
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0,(float)(Math.sin((float)(Sys.getTime())*0.002f))*2+1, 0);
        sphere.draw(1, 70, 20);
    glPopMatrix();

    SimpleEntities.drawBox(50, 0.25f, 50);
    */

    //-----

    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, ~0);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP,GL_ZERO);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);//Turn blending on
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);//Turn off light to draw shadow without normals
    glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f);//Exsisting color (on plane) is modulated with 50% black


    //-----

    //Draw shadow of objects on the floor
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    drawSceneShadow();
    /*do->
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0, 0.0005f, 0);
        glMultMatrix(BufferUtils.arrayToBufferFloat(shadow_floor));
        drawSphere();
    glPopMatrix();
    */
    //-----

    //Restore original mode
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    //-----


    updateCam();//check keys and do a gluLookAt();

    Display.update();
    Display.sync(GameInfo.FPS);//--> 60FPS

    TimeLogic.showFPS();

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
        //pauseMenuShow = true;
        //showPauseMenu();
        render = false;
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

SimpleEntities.drawBox function:

```
public static void drawBox(float x, float y, float z){
    // cut the quad in parts for light reflection

    float cutx = 0;
    for(float i=0;i<x;i+=cutSize){
        cutx++;
    }
    float cuty = 0;
    for(float i=0;i<y;i+=cutSize){
        cuty++;
    }
    float cutz = 0;
    for(float i=0;i<z;i+=cutSize){
        cutz++;
    }
    //-------------------------
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(x,y,z);
    glBegin (GL_QUADS);

    //glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    //face 1 
    glNormal3f(-1, 1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1,-1); glVertex3f( 1, 1,-1);
    glVertex3f( 1,-1,-1); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    //face 2 bottom
    glNormal3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1); glVertex3f( 1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f( 1,-1, 1); glVertex3f(-1,-1, 1);
    // face 3 
    glNormal3f( 1,-1, 1);
    glVertex3f( 1,-1, 1); glVertex3f( 1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f( 1, 1,-1); glVertex3f( 1, 1, 1);

    //face 4 top
    //--> x;z
    //System.out.println("number of part:\nx:"+cutx+"\ny:"+cuty+"\nz:"+cutz+"\n-----------------------");
    boolean first = true;
    for(float ix=0;ix<cutx;ix++){
        for(float iz=0;iz<cutz;iz++){
            /*
            glColor3f(30, 30, 30);
            if(first){
                glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
                first = false;
            }
            if(ix+1 == cutx && iz+1 == cutz){
                glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
                first = false;
            }
            */
            //-1 ==> i/cutx*2-1
            //1  ==> i/(cutx+1)*2-1
            /*
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println("iz="+iz);
            System.out.println("cutz="+cutz);
            System.out.println("=>"+iz+"/"+cutz+"*2-1");
            System.out.println("=>"+div+"*2-1");
            System.out.println("=>"+(div*2)+"-1");
            System.out.println("=>"+(div*2-1));
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            */
            //System.out.println("-1 => "+iz+"/"+cutz+"*2-1 = "+n1);
            //System.out.println("1  => ("+iz+"/"+cutz+"+1)*2-1 = "+(iz/(cutz+1)*2-1));
            //float milis = (float)Math.sin(((double)System.currentTimeMillis())/5000);

            float overx = (ix+1)/cutx-0.5f;
            float underx = ix/cutx-0.5f;
            float overz = (iz+1)/cutz-0.5f;
            float underz = iz/cutz-0.5f;

            /*
            float overx = (ix+1)/cutx;
            float underx = ix/cutx;
            float overz = (iz+1)/cutz;
            float underz = iz/cutz;
            */
            glNormal3f(overx*2, 1, underz*2);
            glVertex3f(overx*2, 1, underz*2); glVertex3f(underx*2, 1, underz*2);
            glVertex3f(underx*2, 1, overz*2); glVertex3f(overx*2, 1, overz*2);
        }
    }
    //glNormal3f( 1, 1,-1);
    //glVertex3f( 1, 1,-1); glVertex3f(-1, 1,-1);
    //glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1); glVertex3f( 1, 1, 1);
    //face 5 
    glNormal3f(-1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1); glVertex3f(-1, 1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1); glVertex3f(-1,-1, 1);
    //face 6 
    glNormal3f( 1,-1, 1);
    glVertex3f( 1,-1, 1); glVertex3f( 1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1); glVertex3f(-1,-1, 1);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix(); 
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this bug ?
thanks !

Sorry for my bad english --'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the shadow using a cone from the light source which extends above the object causing the wrong shadow when the  object is below ground.

You need to draw volumetric shadows by extending the shadow-casting object in the direction opposite to the light source, capped at the object.

Google "Volumetric Shadows" or "Shadow volume".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_volume

[image]

Notice that the shadow volumes don't extend toward the light, only away from it (light cap).

[Chapter 9. Efficient Shadow Volume Rendering](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems/part-ii-lighting-and-shadows/chapter-9-efficient-shadow-volume-rendering)

[image]

Comment: I've found the Nehe tutorial converted for lwjgl ([link](http://flyingkakapo.blogspot.fr/2012/10/shadow-volumes-with-lwjgl.html)). Do you think it's a good choise ? or can I only add one or two lines to make this doing right ?